# Problem with deciphering query

Tags: soql, query

I am new to a Salesforce organisation and currently I am trying to make sense of the organisation's apex code. I came across this query and for the life of me I can't figure out what it does. This is probably a pretty noob question but my experience with queries are pretty limited and it would be a great help if anyone can figure out and explain what the query does.

```
Query='SELECT Name, Id 
         FROM Form__c 
        WHERE Name > \"+ BName+'\' 
          AND Candidate__c =\"+ candidateID +'\' 
        ORDER BY Name ASC'
```

For context, all of the variables above are strings (even the ids).

I have googled the syntax for SOQL but in this case the backslashes for the single and double quote characters and random + signs are really throwing me off here. Does anyone know what the query does??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query returns a list of sObjects from the database. Each object will contain only two fields: `Name` and `Id`. There will be only objects for a particular candidate with Id equals to  `candidateID` and his/her name need to be [greater than](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) `BName` string.

Finally this list [will be sorted](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) by `Name` field in ascending (ASC) order.
The backslashes are used here for [escaping purpose](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm). The query is sent as a string to the compiler, so all "injected" charactes need to be escaped.

Example apex code -> generated query:
`WHERE Name > \''+ BName+'\'` will to `WHERE Name > 'Smith'` 
[Read more about ascaping here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm)

You can read more about SOQL: [Salesforce SOQL Reference.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. Does this mean that the backslashes for the single and double quote characters and concatenations do nothing??

Comment: @mwh Updated my answer. Backslashes are used for the escaping purpose.

Comment: Thanks so much I understand now. Btw, wouldn't 
WHERE Name > :BName
do the same thing?

Comment: @mwh Yep exactly. It will work.